# Example of OpenId implementation with Everyauth

Tags: node.js, openid, passport.js, everyauth

I wish to implement OpenID on a Node.js server with Everyauth, and I was looking for an example to guide me, since I am quite new to Javascript and Node. I am aware of the everyauth documentation, but still, if I could play around with a project/example I would appreciate.

For Passport, I found good examples here:

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openid/tree/master/examples/signon
- https://gist.github.com/2963889

But is there anything equivalent for Everyauth?

Regards,

Comment: Passport is the #1 authentication library to go with node.js. Why insist on everyauth?

Comment: @Patrick: Thank you. I have to add OpenID functionality to a project that is already using Everyauth. Switching to Passport is always an option, that I find attractive the more I look into it...

Comment: did you ever find, or do you have a working example?

Comment: @ccyoung: I opted for Passport. It works very well. I stoped looking for Everyauth examples...